# How to programmatically delete taxonomies when a module is uninstalled?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, installation

Taxonomy vocabularies are in the CMI as of Drupal 8, but I want to also keep the Taxonomy terms in code. I am programmatically creating terms in a custom module.

```
function taxonomy_vocab_install() {
  foreach (taxonomy_term_info() as $term_info) {
    $term = Term::create(array(
      'parent' => array(),
      'name' => $term_info['name'],
      'description' => [
        'value' => $term_info['description'],
        'format' => 'full_html',
      ],
        'vid' => 'department',
    ));
    $term->save();
  };
};
```

Now, I want to delete the terms on uninstall, but [taxonomy_term_delete](https://www.drupal.org/node/1400186) is depreciated. Any help on how to programmatically delete the created taxonomy terms in D8 when the module is uninstalled would be greatly appreciated.

```
function taxonomy_department_uninstall() {
  // ?? 
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did not test it myself, but as far as I see in the [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!taxonomy!src!Entity!Term.php/class/Term/8), Term is using [Entity::delete()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!Entity.php/function/Entity%3A%3Adelete/8). You might try to load the terms you wish to delete and call this method directly on them:

```
$term->delete();
```

Comment: Another option is to call the storage handler's delete method on an array of entity ids. I do not have any metrics about performance, but my gut feeling is that this would be faster.

Comment: Deleting multiple terms at once would definitely be faster, but not that $storage->delete() expects an array of entities, not ids.